# smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed Might this result from an already open connection?

Tags: python3, email, smtp, yahoo

The traceback points to:   `smtpserver.login(email, pwd)`
I've checked the recommended setup, and experimented and this is were I end.  I've had the email app open separate from this testing, but believed it closed.  Is there a process for which I should search?
What other info is needed?

Comment: Does this tell you anything?   
 
smtpserver.login(email, pwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 432, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")

Comment: Generating an application password and ignoring the suggested use of port 465 made the problem disappear.  From that info, I might have solved my problem quicker if the error message had said "Something Happened?".